# Significato di "recessivo" in questo passaggio

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Andammo insieme a vedere «Porto delle Nebbie», lo trovammo meraviglioso, e ci confessammo a vicenda di esserci identificati coi protagonisti: Giulia smilza e mora con la eterea Michèle Morgan dagli occhi di gelo, io mite e **recessivo** con Jean Gabin disertore, fascinatore, bullo e morto ammazzato: assurdo, e poi quei due si amavano e noi no, non è vero?

Ho cercato l'aggettivo "recessivo" su parecchi dizionari, inclusi il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/recessivo) e il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00641.jpg), ma le differenti accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso nel contesto del testo. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Comment: In genetica un carattere "recessivo" non è dominante; qui potrebbe essere inteso nel senso di "timido" o "remissivo".

Comment: Probabilmente sì intende ***remissivo***:  Che si rimette di buon grado, senza contrasti e resistenze, al volere o al parere altrui: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/remissivo/

Comment: Concordo con Hachi. Secondo me i dizionari che hai consultato danno un significato troppo ristretto e non contemplano un uso più figurato del termine che, in effetti, potrebbe essere reso meglio con *remissivo*. Poi, stride un po' avvicinare "bullo" e "remissivo/recessivo", ma chi può realmente dire che cosa intendesse l'autore? Magari l'effetto stridente è stato usato a bella posta.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Certo che il contrasto è voluto. Hai letto anche il resto? Così come la mora si identifica con una celebre attrice bionda con gli occhi chiari, il mite si identifica con un bullo. “Assurdo”, come commenta il narratore.

Comment: @DaG no, avevo dato appena una mezza scorsa (queste "pillole" mi annoiano). E' vero, l'autore stesso qualifica come assurdi gli accostamenti.

Comment: Il significato è chiaramente *remissivo*; capita che una parola resti in mente e scappi nello scritto al posto di un'altra più corretta: l'assonanza è evidente, del resto.

Comment: @egreg quindi Primo Levi poteva fare di meglio?

Comment: @egreg: È possibilissimo che la parola sia “scappata”, ma è anche possibile che Levi, che non era proprio un ignorante, abbia usato di proposito in modo figurato un termine proprio di una disciplina scientifica, lui scienziato e scrittore, in particolare proprio nel _Sistema periodico_, che è un testo autobiografico ma che usa come filo conduttore gli elementi chimici.

Comment: @DaG Certamente!